# Router not connecting to the internet

Tags: internet, router

I had a weird problem this morning with my router - it's an Alice Gate VoIP 2 Plus WI-FI - not connecting to the internet after more or less 1 hour online (I'm always connected with the ethernet cable). The led status lights for *Power, WI-FI, ADSL, Internet, Service* should be on in order to be connected and navigate online. The problem was that the leds *ADSL, Internet* were off and I did not know why because it never happened before.

I looked at the stats in the settings and the numbers for Bytes/Packages for both Sent/Received were there and increasing but I couldn't connect to the internet. I called tech support, they checked and told me to keep the router on for 48 hours because they were checking it.

I've reset it twice before and after I called tech support and it still did not work so after about 2 hours of waiting I tried connecting using WI-FI and the leds 'magically' turned on, first the ADSL and Internet(Internet led always turns on last). At this point I'm curious what could of caused this and I'm doubting that the tech-support guys did something. What could of been the problem with the ethernet cable not connecting in the first place? It always works.
What do the tech support guys normally do when they tell me to keep the router on so they can 'check it'?

PS: I'm using ubuntu 32 bit

Comment: Sometimes you can fix this yourself by disconnecting the power from the router for 30 seconds (hard reset), then plug power back in, it will take 30 - 60 seconds or so for the router to re establish the connection to the ISP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that when the ISP tells you to leave you "router" on for 48 hours, they are giving themselves a lot of time to do a series of troubleshooting exercises. One of them is to connect to the router and test its connectivity. Something else they do is a "rip and rebuild" which is basically when they rip your information out of the DHCP server and put you back in to test for a corrupted entry in the DHCP server (This has happened to me before). I'm not sure of everything that they do, but these are a couple of things that they do. I am guessing that they may have did a "rip and rebuild" with your IP address on the DHCP server.

If you think it was an internal issue, have you checked to make sure that the Ethernet cable is still good (i.e. the 8 wires are still to the end of the RJ-45 connector)? If this is the issue, you will either notice no internet connectivity with your computer, or it will be screwy (fades in and out).

If you have anymore question, feel free to comment back with them.